# Touch events belong to HTML5 device access class?

Tags: events, html, touch

This probably isn't a hard one but couldn't find any info on it. HTML5 is sorted into 8 classes: http://www.w3.org/html/logo/#the-technology. Under the `device access` class is the `geolocation API`, but what about touch events?

Are they classified under device access since they are exclusively available on a multi touch "device"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they are, device access is more about accessing and controlling peripherals on the device (ie. cameras, scanners, GPS devices) than it is about user input.  There is a [draft Touch Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) available from the W3C, and it seems to be broadly in line with [what's implemented in iOS WebKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW22).